# How to throw connector error for actual process task

Tags: oracle, exception, task, oim

I'm quite new to OIM, and I'm frequently tracing error from both oim and connector  (including custom connectors) error logs based on task timestamp, I found this is really time wasting.

I understand that we can use response code mapping at task level to differentiate the errors, but for connector errors, we can only see "Connector Exception".

Is there any better way to display error for such cases?

Additional question: there are errors caused by connection to target, which will happen to all tasks. In this case where should I handle the response code at a time?

Comment: your additional question is not clear to me

Comment: Let's say if a "target application" is down, all the tasks will fail. Other than having monitoring, I would like to also display on task saying it was caused by "unable to connect", but configure task by task(response code)  is time consuming as I got more than 30 tasks per process definition, and around 50 process definition I need to configure response code mapping.

Answer (score 0):

The only way i know to get what you would like to accomplish is to modify the connector bundles/custom adapters that are being used by the process tasks.  You can then add custom responses based on the errors you catch.  Those responses can then be added to the process task as responses that can be seen in the resource history of an account.  Which will likely take more time than visiting the em console to view log messages.

Other items to look into:

Configuring retry on failed process tasks.  This way if you encounter an error OIM can try the task again after a specified period of time.

Utilizing Open Tasks, this is a good area to use to retry/view multiple failed process tasks.  It doesn't give you more information than the logs will, but it can help you find patterns and/or resolve multiple failed tasks at a time.